# Weird shadow effect on render and preview

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, error, shadows

Anyone knows why this shadow error appears when I put a normal map on my model? It appears when I render or rotate the camera around the object. It seems to be an error with the pattern but i can't resolve this.

[image]

Comment: Hello maybe the normal map node is set to srgb instead of non-color, or please pack your images and share your file

Comment: To me this looks like a quite common Moiré effect, because you have a very fine structure that cannot be resolved by your image resolution. That's why especially in the early days people were not allowed to wear clothes with very small patterns when they appear on TV talk shows. [Wikipedia: Moiré pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern)